# Match array of string elements to string column in Pyspark

Tags: arrays, string, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What's the best way to match (and join) an array of string elements to a string column in a dataframe?

| String_column | Array_of_strings |
| --- | --- |
| string1 | element1:string4, element 2: string 2 |
| string2 | element1:string1, element 2: string 4 |

The expected output would be:

| String_column | Array_of_strings |
| --- | --- |
| string1 | element1:string1, element 2: string 4 |
| string2 | element1:string4, element 2: string 2 |

Rather than matching, I'm doing a self join with this dataframe in which I match all the strings that have an overlapping string in the array of strings.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output? And what do you mean by "match"?

Comment: Just updated the question so hopefully it now makes more sense

Comment: I still don't understand the logic. Why is string3 replaced, but not string4? Both of them have overlapping strings `string`.

Comment: okay, just did another edit. I am not really a star with creating these tables on this platform. The goal is to match array of string elements with another column (using a self join) when any of the string elements is equal to any of the strings in the string_column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a join using an `array_contains` condition:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.select('String_column').join(
    df.select('Array_of_strings'), 
    F.array_contains('Array_of_strings', F.col('String_column'))
)

result.show()
+-------------+------------------+
|String_column|  Array_of_strings|
+-------------+------------------+
|      string1|[string1, string4]|
|      string2|[string4, string2]|
+-------------+------------------+
```